# How to access request object accross all templates in velocity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I a newbie in velocity templates with spring. I am using VelocityViewResolver to server vm files. I want to get the $request.getLocale() but unfortunately no request object is null.

I can access request object to the vm file(create_user.vm) which is set into context by controller directly but request object is not available in other vm files like header.vm. I need locale to pick the javascript file based on the locale.

I know I can pass the request object to header.vm or other vms like #parse("header.vm", $request) but I am not satisfied by this approach. Please let me know the right way..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "createuser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createUser(ModelMap model) throws SQLException {

    ......
    .......

    ModelAndView courseModelView = new ModelAndView ("create_user");
    return courseModelView;
}
```

My servelt-dispatcher.xml has velocity configuration as fellow.

```
<!--  Presentation Configuration  -->
<bean id="velocityConfig"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/vm/" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"

   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml"> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Normally, when you use toolboxConfigLocation the view implementation should be VelocityToolboxView and this creates a context and exposes request, response, application and servletContext. May be hook in with the debugger gives some idea what goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you modify your controller method as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "createuser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createUser(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
    ......
    .......
    ModelAndView courseModelView = new ModelAndView ("create_user");
    courseModelView.addObject("locale", request.getLocale());
    return courseModelView;
}
```

Then the 'locale' object will be available in your model to be used in the template.